# Need to convert key=value text list to JSON stream in dot net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, configuration

I am receiving the Key=Value pairs list as a MemoryStream :

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
:
keyN=valueN
```

I'm using AddJsonStream() to bind the configuration in the dotnet core.
How can I convert this type of MemoryStream key/value data to JSONStream like below?

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   :
   "keyN":"valueN",
}
```

so it can bind as a configuration in dot net. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used following way:

```
// Create a dictionary to load content of configuration
Dictionary<string, string> _werFileContent = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(result.Result.Content))
{
     string _line;
     while ((_line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
                string[] keyvalue = _line.Split('=');
                if (keyvalue.Length == 2)
                {
                    _werFileContent.Add(keyvalue[0], keyvalue[1]);
                }
     }
}

// Converting Key=Value extracted data to string
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_werFileContent);

// Converting to Stream
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( json));
```